# get short file name when LFN name has two extensions

Tags: batch-file, windows-xp-sp3

I am having an issue getting short file name (SFN) in a batch script to be passed to an old program that only takes 8.3 short file names as command line arguments.  I did some testing at cmd.exe prompt here is output to find what was causing problem:

```
> dir /x *.vi
 Volume in drive C is DSK_C
 Volume Serial Number is FC79-4140

 Directory of c:\Documents and Settings

08/04/2016  10:48               211 Z12TXT~1.VI  z12.TXT.vi
08/04/2016  10:48               211 Z123TX~1.VI  z123.TXT.vi
               2 File(s)            422 bytes
               0 Dir(s)   3,599,233,024 bytes free

> for /F "usebackq tokens=* delims=&" %A in (`echo "c:\Documents and Settings\z1
23.TXT.vi"`) do @echo "result=%~sfA"
"result=c:\DOCUME~1\Z123TX~1.VI"

> for /F "usebackq tokens=* delims=&" %A in (`echo "c:\Documents and Settings\z1
2.TXT.vi"`) do @echo "result=%~sfA"
"result=c:\DOCUME~1\Z12TXT~1.VIgs\z12.TXT.vi"
```

In the last command output `result=c:\DOCUME~1\Z12TXT~1.VIgs\z12.TXT.vi`  should be `result=c:\DOCUME~1\Z12TX~1.VI`.  I tried various combinations like adding `delims` but can't find a solution other than scraping `dir` output into a var.  It looks like if filename is less than or equal to 7 characters (`%~nA` part) and contains a period then `%~sfA` or `%~snxA` has incorrect result. Is that right and are there any other simpler solutions?

Edit Apr 12:
Just to clarify path is not a problem but in the above example `%~sfA` path is corrupt but `%~sdpA` would be `c:\DOCUME~1\Z12TXT~1.VI\`

Comment: A `.` is legal in a filename. Only the part after the last `.` is the extension.

Comment: Ididn't say it was illegal, I said it was legal.

Comment: It says this is normal.

Comment: @Noodles the program I am testing with when passed argument  `z12.TXT.vi` fails (that is a LFN), and passing `Z12TXT~1.VI` works (that is a SFN). If you think about, for example, running MS-DOS OS that would not allow you to create an 8.3 conforming file name `z12.TXT.vi` you would need to remove `.` and created `Z12TXT~1.VI`.   `z12.TXT.vi`  is not a SFN see  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename.

Comment: I don't see any problem. Files don't have two extensions.

Comment: @Noodles The issue is that the object is to generate a SFN suitable for inputting to a procedure that expects 8.3 format, wherein `.` is not a valid character except as the separator between the name and extension.

Comment: You call api calls - The GetShortPathName function retrieves the short path form of a specified input path.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
SET "parent=%sourcedir%\"
CALL :resolvedir
for /F "tokens=4delims= " %%A in ('
dir /x /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.vi"^|FINDstr /e /i /L ".vi"
') do echo "result=%parent%%resultd%%%A"


GOTO :EOF

:resolvedir
SET "resultd="
:rdloop
FOR %%J IN ("%parent:~0,-1%") DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=\" %%G IN ("%parent%") DO IF "%%H"=="" (
  GOTO :eof
 ) ELSE (
  FOR /F "tokens=1*delims=>" %%A IN ('dir /ad /x "%parent%\.."') DO (
   IF "%%B" neq "" FOR /f "tokens=1*delims= " %%D IN ("%%B") DO (
    IF /i "%%D"=="%%~nxJ" SET "resultd=%%D\%resultd%"&SET "parent=%%~dpJ"
    IF /i "%%E"=="%%~nxJ" SET "resultd=%%D\%resultd%"&SET "parent=%%~dpJ"
   )
  )
 )
)

GOTO rdloop
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

I'm assuming the source directory is a full pathname including drive letter. No doubt this will show sensitivity to certain characters like the usual suspects, but keep the names to long-pure-alphameric-and spaces-and nice-characters and all should be well.

---

If there is no need to resolve the directoryname as short, then the above simplifies to

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
for /F "tokens=4delims= " %%A in ('
dir /x /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.vi"^|FINDstr /e /i /L ".vi"
') do echo "result=%%A"
```

Where the setting and use of of `sourcedir` is merely for testing purposes.